# не работает медиа запрос, хром игнорирует медиа в наве

Tags: css, media-queries

тестил похожий код на новом файле, все работало, тут ничего не меняется, в инспекторе код в медиа игнорируется

```
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
 nav{
    width: 85%;
    background: #252b3d;
    height: 8%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
 }
}


nav {
 width: 15%;
 background: #252b3d;
 height: 88%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -1%;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

в хеде html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/indexd.css" id="theme-link" media="screen">
```

Comment: поменяй местами. Что ниже, то браузер и обрабатывает. То есть, сначала он присваивает свойства в @media{ nav }, потом перечеркивает их и ставит то, что в nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить ваш `Viewport` на `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">`